# SVG looks different in browser then in WordPress

Tags: adobe-illustrator, website-design, svg, plugin

I exported my logo to wordpress.
This is my logo on my site
http://kopjezoektfamilie.nl/test/

But when I open my logo in my browser (chrome)
it looks like this:

[image]

I want my logo to look like the last one. I don't know why the blue background isn't transferred as well.. (I already tried outlining everything and not outlining everything and only outlining the text.

I also used every svg support plugin I could find but nothing works :(

Please help

Comment: I can't see what's wrong there at all. They  both look the same to me. Maybe the difference is so small that I can't see it. I'm also on my phone... Is it possible it's a browser support issue?

Comment: I see this - https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICdzn.png - something broken top left, but I can(almost) read the text. I'd probably avoid text *that* light, as you're going to get caught in screen calibration variance.

Comment: Right now there's no such logo in the link provided... It would be more useful to have a link that doesn't break, and screenshots of what you see and what is wrong with the version on the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems there's a "background-logo.png" file that is not there in the wordpress link.

Theres a **fallback** to a png file in case the SVG doesn't load or isn't supported.

[image]

Seems you don't have that fallback image in Wordpress.

And for the record.. I see no "blue background" anywhere.